# Mapping one range of integers to another

Tags: c#

Say that I have a set of numbers from `0` to `255` and I would like to be able to map that range to a smaller one of `0` through `63`, so that each value in the smaller set represents four values from the larger set.  I haven't been able to find anything in standard C# that would allow me to do that.

I can do so manually if I know all of the values ahead of time, by dividing an input by 4, i.e.:

```
int input = 127;
int pInput = 127 / 4; // 31
```

The major problem with that method is that it's not entirely usable to me, due to the fact that my number sets will vary in their ranges.  I could take the larger set and divide it by the smaller set to get the divisor value, which would be placed where the `4` is:

```
int divisor = lSet.Count / sSet.Count;  // 256 / 64 = 4
int pInput = input / divisor;           // 127 / 4 = 31
```

...but it's not an entirely accurate method, considering I'm dealing with integer values and the divisor won't always be accurate.

Has anyone dealt with something like this or has a possible solution?

**EDIT:**

To clarify the goal here, say that you have a range of inputs of `0` through `255`, but you can only process numbers of `0` through `63`.  I want to map the two ranges, so that if any input from the larger set maps to a particular value in the lower set.  Note that there can be different sets, and the ones I use are simply as examples.

It's possible to have a set of `0` through `136` and a set of `0` through `25`.  The above formula won't properly map the two, since the divisor would be `5` and the top value of `136` would not map to the value of `25`.  It would instead map to `27`, which is out of range.  m-y's solution would not work here either.

Here's an illustration that doesn't rely on numbers, but rather a concept:

```
|     n1    |     n2    |     n3    | ... |     ni    |
| n1 ... nm | nm ... nq | nq ... nr | ... | nj ... ni |
```

Comment: Several questions for clarity. Do neighboring numbers have to map to the same or neighboring numbers in the smaller set? I.e. if 128 maps to 32 does 129 have to map to 32 or 33? Is 0 a special case? Do you want extras spread out over the mapping?

Comment: By extra I mean, if you map 1 through 20 to 1 through 3, should the three buckets (1,2,3) have 6/6/8 mappings, 6/7/7, 7/6/7, our does it not matter?

Comment: You should explain why this is a solution a bit more, for future readers. For example, why did the other solution not work, what are the variables in this formula, etc.

Comment: Your requirement was that "each value in the smaller set represents four values from the larger set". However, in your "solution" you have five values in each of 0, 21 and 42, and only one in 63.

Comment: @ClickRick That was an example.  But you're right... something's off with that solution.

Comment: That's my point - it's a bad one. Your "solution" does not meet your own stated "requirement".

Comment: Try using smaller numbers while you're defining the question. Perhaps no bigger than 5, definitely no more than 10. That way it'll be easier to explain and illustrate.

Comment: 0 ... 136 doesn't evenly map into 0 ... 25, so which sets get the additional item in their set?

Comment: @m-y Correct. That was my concern with my method. As far as the extra number, it probably won't matter.  I think it's best to map it to the lowest or highest counterpart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the modulus operator, `%`:

```
var result = x % 64;
```

---

Update: I'll expand on my answer. The modulus operator will give the remainder after division. So, in this situation `0 % 64 = 0`, `1 % 64 = 1`, ... `63 % 64 = 63`, `64 % 64 = 0`, `65 % 64 = 1`, etc ...

---

In the example above, the modulus operator would map the values of (0, 64, 128, 192) to 0, (1, 65, 129, 193) to 1, ... (63, 127, 191, 255) to 63. But, if you are looking to create the sets in the format of (0, 1, 2, 3) = 1, (4, 5, 6, 7) = 2, ..., (252, 253, 254, 255) = 63. Then you have the right answer already:

```
var divisor = (double)largeSet.Count / smallSet.Count;
var result = x / divisor;
```

If you are worried about zero-based numbers, i.e. the x you pass in is 256 (which is 255 in zero based), then simply subtract one first:

```
 var result = (x - 1) / divisor;
 // (256 - 1) / 4
 // 255 / 4 = 63.
```

Comment: How does having remainder help me at all?  I'm failing to understand your solution.  Say that input is `65` based on the larger set, the counterpart of the lower range should be `16`.  I'm very well aware of the modulus operator... so I'd rather see a solution to the specific problem I have.

Comment: @B.K. If that's the case, I'm failing to understand your requirements. Please review your question and provide requirements that are more understandable. I don't understand how you get that the *upper range of 65 maps to a lower range of 16*?

Comment: Sorry, I can leave my answer as is until you clarify how the heck the set of **five** numbers (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) maps to 0, yet the next set only contains **four** numbers, and the last set contains a single number (255) which maps to 63? That is a mapping that makes no sense.

Comment: Say you have a larger set of `0` through `136` and a smaller set of `0` through `25`.  `137 / 26 = 5` -> `137 / 5 = 27`  So, even if you subtract `1` from the input, you won't get the right value: `(136 - 1) / 5 = 27` ->  `27` is out of range.

Comment: Disregard that mapping solution I had, it was wrong.  However, check my comment above regarding your solution and why it doesn't work.

Comment: @B.K.: I've updated the answer to make the divisor a `double` so you can create sets that are uneven: 0 ... 137 => 0 ... 25 would get a divisor of 138 / 26 = ~5.3. So, `0 / 5.3 = 0`, `1 / 5.3 = 1`, ..., `137 / 5.3 = 25`

Comment: That's an excellent idea... using floating point divisor and then cast the result to an int.  Thanks.